# How am I able to access the Firebase variable AcX in my user?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My groupmate was able to send Arduino data containing accelerometer data to our Firebase database. How am I able to access the AcX, AcY, and AcZ? I tried using the read and write Firebase functionalities but I was getting confused on how to access it from Users/Ac_/and the Unique ID was throwing me off.

[image: Example of Database]

[image: Users group of database]

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("AcX");

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // want to print out values of accelerometer data here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: I apologize, please see my updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems: there is no node `/Users/Acx`, so when you create `ref` it points to a non-existing node. Most likely you want to show the data for all users, to let's make `ref` point to `/Users`:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
```

Then we load all data at that location, carefully handle the error in `onCancelled` and then in `onDataChange` can loop over all the child nodes with:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            DataSnapshot acxSnapshot = userSnapshot.getChild("AcX");
            for (DataSnapshot valueSnapshot = acxSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("firebase", valueSnapshot.getValue(Long.class));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

So you'll see that in `onDataChange` we use a loop over `getChildren` to navigate over the keys that we don't know. Also note that giving the snapshots meaningful names makes it significantly easier to see what's going on.